# add space 5 times at the beginning of each line in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am looking for a command line or bash script that would add space 5 times before the beginning of each line in a file.

for example:

```
abc
```

after adding spaces 5 times

```
      abc
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/     /' <file>
```

will replace the start of each line with 5 spaces.  The `-i` modifies the file in place, `-e` gives some code for `sed` to execute.  `s` tells `sed` to do a subsitution, `^` matches the start of the line, then the part between the second two `/` characters is what will replace the part matched in the beginning, i.e., the start of the line in this example.

Comment: I think I like the simplicity of your answer more as opposed to the others I've seen.

Comment: This is a great answer btw. I love it when each step is explained. I know this is old, but props and thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `sed`

```
sed 's_^_     _' tmpin > tmpout
```

Or `awk`

```
awk '{print "     " $0}' tmpin > tmpout
```

Or paste (Thanks [cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200620/38906))

```
:| paste -d' ' - - - - - file
```

Watch out. These can be addictive. You can solve many simple problems, but the time will come where you need to upgrade to a full scripting language.

**Edit:** Sed script simplified based on Eric Renouf's answer.

Comment: True, I just find it helpful to think in this way, because I nearly always use sed and awk in pipes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use many standard tools, example with `paste`:

```
:| paste -d' ' - - - - - file
```

or shorter with `awk`:

```
awk '{$1="     "$1}1' file
```

or more portable with `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$_=" "x5 .$_' file
```

Comment: sir can you explain what `: |` does?

Comment: It's no-op operator

Comment: `:|` means run the command `:`, which successfully does nothing and outputs nothing (explained by `builtins(1)`), and then the pipe `|` passes that command's standard output as standard input into `paste(1)`.

Comment: Perhaps a clearer version of the above paste invocation would be `paste -d' ' - - - - - file < /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/^/     /|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close