# Replacing new line character with a pipe and a new line character

Tags: text-processing

I am using `ksh`.

I have a file `temp.txt` with some pipe delimited data.

```
one|two|three|four|five
abc|def|pqr|lmn|xyz
```

As clear from example, the record ends with a new line character after the data value in the last column.

However, I want the record to end with a pipe delimiter and a new line character as below:

```
one|two|three|four|five|
abc|def|pqr|lmn|xyz|
```

I tried the following commands but still unsuccessful:

```
tr '\n' '|\n' < temp.txt
```

and

```
sed -i 's/\n/|\n/g' temp.txt
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you have joined lines, the `\n` doesn't appear in `sed`'s pattern space: the end-of-line anchor is `$`.

So with GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/$/|/' temp.txt
```

Comment: Great. This works. Did not know end-of-line is $ for sed. Thanks!

Comment: May I also add that the ignoring of `\n` (et al) will even apply to their hexadecimal representation! That means in practice, that `sed 's/someregex\x0a/something/'` will fail as well, because `sed` will ignore the control character specified in hex in the regex. I had to learn this the hard way back then, when I had to debug the actual cause why my parser did not operate the expected way.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `sed`, you could replace the end of line with `|` by using:

```
sed -i 's/$/|/' temp.txt
```

That will match the end of the line and "replace" it with `|`, but of course the line will still end and keep its `\n`

Comment: Great. This works. Did not know end-of-line is $ for sed. Thanks!

Comment: The `$` end-of-line marker is a regular expression feature, not specific to sed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paste`:

```
$ :|paste -d'|' file - > new_file
one|two|three|four|five|
abc|def|pqr|lmn|xyz|
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -i.bak -ple '$_.="|"' file
```

Comment: +1. Could you explain the `paste` a bit..

Comment: @heemayl: `:` is no-op and it was piped to `paste`. `paste` merge lines from `file` and stdin (which is empty) with `|` as delimiter.

Comment: hmm, excessively clever for my taste (and I love a dash of clever!). How about `paste -d'|' file /dev/null` ?

Comment: @glennjackman: It's ok in this case, but can cause long typing when you need multiple `/dev/null`, something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200620/38906).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/.*/&|/' file
```

Special character `&` corresponds to the pattern matched in the RHS.